# require Mustache templates in requirejs

Tags: requirejs, mustache

I'm using mustache templates in requirejs with the text plugin.

```
define(['text!templates/popups.html', 'mustache'], function (Mustache,popups) {

var mustacheTmpl = Mustache.render(popups, {jData:jsonObj});

}
```

I would like to call the mustache templates within the module based on a condition like

```
define(['mustache'], function (Mustache) {
    if ($('.element').length) {
        require(['text!templates/mustachetemplate'],
            function(mustachetemplate) {
                var mustacheTmpl = Mustache.render(mustachetemplate, {jData:jsonObj});
        })
    }
}
```

How is that possible?

Comment: Yeah that's entirely possible.

Comment: What does not work in your second code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it actually is working the way I do it. The reason why it was failing was because some other code was blocking.